# How to raise an event when another event is raised?

Tags: c#, events

I have an application that handles the `OnQuit` event of another running application. How can I raise an additional (custom) event when said `OnQuit` event is handled.

My `OnQuit` handler:

```
private void StkQuit()
{
   _stkApplicationUi.OnQuit -= StkQuit;
   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_stkApplicationUi);
   Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: The same way you create any other event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will usually have an event in my view interface like so:

```
public interface ITestView
    {
        event EventHandler OnSomeEvent;
    }
```

Then from a presenter constructor I'll wire up those events:

```
public class TestPresenter : Presenter
{
    ITestView _view;

    public TestPresenter(ITestView view)
    {
        _view.OnSomeEvent += new EventHandler(_view_OnSomeEvent);
    }

    void _view_OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code that will run when your StkQuit method is executed
    }
}
```

And from your aspx codebehind:

```
public partial class Test: ITestView
{
     public event EventHandler OnSomeEvent;
     public event EventHandler OnAnotherEvent;

    private void StkQuit()
    {
        _stkApplicationUi.OnQuit -= StkQuit;
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_stkApplicationUi);
        if (this.OnSomeEvent != null)
        {
            this.OnSomeEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Just register this additional event with the _stkApplication after OnQuit has been registered.

```
_stkApplicationUi.OnQuit += StkQuit;
_stkApplicationUi.OnQuitAdditional += AddlQuitHandler;
```

where AddlQuitHandler is the handler for the custom event